# Unpacking an array_value()'d $_POST array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I'm having some issues that I suspect are from misunderstanding how to handle $_POST data from a web form. It's racking my brains, because my method works in one scenario, but breaks in its successor.

In a nutshell: I can call key=>value pairs of $_POST in a method, but I can't manipulate the $_POST array itself, which always returns as 1.

Initial Scenario. Refer to comments for context & gripes. This method works:

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    $post = $_POST; // I'm aware $_POST is a superglobal and can be called within the method
    $cms->addPage($table, $post);
        
}
```

addPage() Method from CMS class:

```php
public function addPage($table, $post) {
    global $db; // SQL object declared in config

    $url = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $post['pageTitle']);

    $vals = array($post['pageTitle'], $post['isRoot'], $post['metaTitle'], $post['metaDesc'], $post['pageCont'], $url, $post['dateCreated'], $post['pageBanner']);

    $cols = array("pageTitle", "isRoot", "metaTitle", "metaDesc", "pageCont", "pageURL", "dateCreated", "pageBanner");

    $types = "sissssss";

    $db->prep_Insert($table, $cols);
    $db->bind_Prep($types, $vals); // This method unpacks the $vals array with ...
    $db->execute_Prep();
    $db->close_Prep();

    $_SESSION['success'] = 'Page Updated';
    header('Location: ' . DIRADMIN . 'manage/pages');
    exit();

}
```

This works fine. Pops right up in the database, and bob's your uncle. But, this CMS should be able to handle multiple form objects, and I don't want to write an add / update method for every custom feature a client might want. So I came up with this:

```php
public function addContent($table, $post, $types) {
    global $db;
    $cols = self::getColumns($table); // Helper method I wrote to get column names from the table being added to
    array_shift($cols); // AUTO_INCREMENT is set in database, so knock off the ID row

    /* This is where it falls apart. All I want is to take the $_POST array 
       I got from the form and reduce it from associative to indexed. 
       The array_values() should do this, right? */
    $post = array_values($post);
    // $post = array_values($_POST); 
    /* Also doesn't work. It doesn't matter if I pass forward the 
       $_POST array as a parameter, or if I call it directly here. */

    /* Second attempt at getting $_POST into an indexed array. I don't need the keys. */
    /*$i = 0;
    $vals = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $vals[$i] = $value;
        $i++;
    }*/

    $db->prep_Insert($table, $cols);
    $db->bind_Prep($types, $post); // This is where I got the initial unpacking error; can't unpack associative arrays. Okay, I'll use array_value($_POST). Except, that always just outputs 1, and breaks the prep statement anyway.

    $db->execute_Prep();
    $db->close_Prep();

    $_SESSION['success'] = 'Page Updated';
    header('Location: ' . DIRADMIN . 'manage/' . $table);
    exit();
}
```

So to reiterate, for some reason I can get $_POST data by its individual key=>value pairs in the initial method, but if I try to manipulate the $_POST array in any way (array_keys(), reset(), foreach loop, etc), it will output as 1. print_r() outputs 1, var_dump() outputs blank, and in the exception message it returns as 1.

Is there some limitation or rule to handling $_POST data that I'm not getting? I can't figure out why I can get key value pairs, but otherwise can't manipulate it at all.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Why do you think you don't need the keys of `$post`? How will you know which values are which?

Comment: I read somewhere that the $_POST array is filled top-to-bottom from the form its being posted from. So if you specifically order your form, you'll know the order the key=>value pairs will be in, and should be able to manipulate it from there.

Comment: That's probably true, although it seems fragile to depend on it. It means you have to carefully arrange for all your query parameters to be in the same order as the form fields.

Comment: If you redesign your form, you then have to modify the query to reorder the parameters.

Comment: But there's no reason why `array_values($post)` wouldn't work.

Comment: I have all that accounted for. The SQL class constructs the query for me just fine, and I set the type string in each form. All I need to know is why $_POST is resisting any manipulation other than calling its key=>values.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you would be getting `1` from `array_values($post)`.

Comment: There are no instances under which `array_values` will return anything other than an array. As Barmar says, you are making this code deliberately obtuse by hoping that `$_POST` is in a given order. You should also avoid using mysqli; if you were using PDO you would avoid all this "sssiissisisis" nonsense and could pass a sanitized POST array directly to the `execute()` method.

Comment: And why not just use a framework like Laravel that just does all this for you?!

Comment: I'm sorry that my code upsets you, miken32. I'm not using Laravel because I'm not familiar with it. I only know vanilla php, and inexpertly, apparently. Now, are you saying $_POST can't be manipulated by array functions? If so, I'll find a different approach.